# apply mathematical  rules stored in database to a variable gotten from human machine interface

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, math, rules

I'm developing a project with Flex, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL, Tomcat, but one of the functionality is: " i have to store a mathematical rule like for example " a+b " into database, then in my human machine interface, i have two fields when user write the variables "a" and "b", then a button with the label calculate which if it's clicked, it'll show bellow the result of applying the rule " a+b " to the variables "a" and "b" which the user previously." 
Now, i'm searching for an Java or Flex API or any other way that will give me the ability to apply a mathematical rule stored in database as string, to variables i got from human machine interface"

Comment: You have 15 questions and none have been accepted.

Comment: I would use a Properties file if you want to store a set of key=value.  Properties has a built in parser so you wouldn't need to add one.

Comment: @Peter I think the OP wants to store the "operation" on the variables (I guess some sort of formula?) in the XML, not the value of those variables.

Comment: there is no real discernible question here and you need to go to your previous questions and click the `CHECKMARK` on the answers that are `correct` to get people to trust that you will follow thru on this one.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you're just looking for [JAXP](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/intro.html), the Java API for XML Processing.

> The Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) is for processing XML data using applications written in the Java programming language. JAXP leverages the parser standards Simple API for XML Parsing (SAX) and Document Object Model (DOM) so that you can choose to parse your data as a stream of events or to build an object representation of it.